# Description page for the "Edit questions and answers" privilege needs an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, privileges

The [description page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) for the "Edit questions and answers" privilege claims:

> Once you have this privilege, the edit link will appear under each
>   post.

I have seen and made use of this edit link long before I got to 2000 reputation, and after I reached 2000 reputation just now, I still see the same link. I guess this text is outdated and needs an **edit**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is changed into:

> The `edit` link is available under each post.

As that being a valid answer to the question "How do I edit posts?" and not conflicting anymore with lower reputation, I suppose this *bug* is solved.

Comment: I do not see the change on the description page. Are you sure there is not a misunderstanding here?

Comment: Oh, that's strange. [On meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) it's changed. I will update the answer.

Comment: That *is* the nature of the reported bug. :) You probably missed the `stackoverflow` tag.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've updated it on meta, it'll be sync'd to the rest of the network soon. Ed: Huh, that's weird. It's not yet propogated.

Comment: Answer rolled back. Credits are for Sathya.