# Should the 2k privileges description be updated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, faq-update-request

There are a couple errors in the description of edit privileges earned at 2,000 reputation.

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>    * to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
>    * to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
>    * correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
>    * add related resources or hyperlinks

should be:

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>    * to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
>    * to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
>    * to correct minor mistakes or add addenda / updates as the post ages
>    * to add related resources or hyperlinks

The two "to"s should be added for consistency. "Addendums" could be updated to "addenda", although I'm not sure this is necessary. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addendum#Plural) says they are both correct, but spell-check does not like "addendums".

**EDIT:** Erwin Brandstetter has pointed out that there is another [request for an edit to the edit page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108858/167443). Looks like this page needs a good review.

Comment: I think you mean ***"may"*** they be updated

Comment: More importantly, [information about edit link is wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108858/description-page-for-the-edit-questions-and-answers-privilege-needs-an-edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. The page was updated, as stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110221/167443).